# Bootstrap 5 Navbar collapse and dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm having a little trouble with my navbar, using bootstrap 5. The navbar doesn't collapse after expanding and the dropdown list doesn't drop.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="" width="100px" src="icons/cake/Asset 4.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SERVICES</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivery</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Event Planning</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger">ORDER ONLINE</button></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of Bootstrap's components require the use of JavaScript to function. Including navbars and dropdowns. I added the relevant source for both font-awesome and the Bootstrap JS.

Read more here on [Bootstrap 5 Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="" width="100px" src="icons/cake/Asset 4.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SERVICES</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivery</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Event Planning</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger">ORDER ONLINE</button></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It works well now. Thanks. 
JavaScript huh.